# Swift UIRefresh Control Drag to refresh in UITableView causes app crash

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, refresh

I have a UIRefreshControll, inside my TableView. All works fine, but if i pull the tableview too fast, the app crashes. 
Error: Fatal error: Index out of range

When i call the function refreshData from a Button, the crash doesnt appear. Is kind of weird because refreshControll doesnt do something different than calling a action.
I hope somebody can help me.

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshData), for: .valueChanged)

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    self.tableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
                } else {
                    self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
                }

@objc private func refreshData() {

    if isRefreshing {
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        return
    }
    isRefreshing = true
    print("refresh")

    guard let url = URL(string: taskURL) else {
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    urlSessionBackground.dataTask(with: request) { (dataOpt, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loading Error", message: "No Internet Connection. Please try again later.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
            return
        }else {
            self.data.removeAll()
            self.userImage.removeAll()
            self.currentData.removeAll()
            self.taskDetails.removeAll()
        }

        guard let dataNew = dataOpt else {
            return
        }

        let appdata = try? JSONDecoder().decode(TaskList.self, from: dataNew)

        for data in appdata!{

              self.data.append(CellData.init(image: UIImage(named: "Profile"), message: data.name, checkImage: data.status))
                self.userImage.append("")

              self.taskDetails.append(TaskDetails.init(status: data.status, assigned: data.assigneUid, time: data.duedateTsUTC, priority: data.priority, desc: data.desc, uid: data.uid))


        }

        self.currentData = self.data

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.searchBar.text = ""
            self.isRefreshing = false
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Fixed it: Used temporary variables to save data and use afterwards. Deleting the data was the problem.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? where exactly is the crash?

Comment: @Simon Liebers can u try to empty tabledata in this section if isRefreshing {
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() //empty your tabledata here  
        return
    }

Comment: @Lu_ On function cellForRowAt indexPath. So on reloading TableView

Comment: @dakrawat Doesnt work in my case.

Comment: if u have crash on cellForRowAt indexPath then it has high probability due to array.so my suggestion would be check the content of array data everytime it gets called because if the arraydata gets changed before and deleted somehow in the middle of tableviewReloading then it gives crash  Also can u do same what i have said earlier to remove all array datat and ther also reload tableview adata

Comment: @dakrawat When i set a breakpoint at the start of refreshData(), it always works, no crash. Without breakpoint, the error only occures, if i drag to the very bottom of the refreshControl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if error != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loading Error", message: "No Internet Connection. Please try again later.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        return
    }else {
        if self.data != nil{            
           self.data.removeAll()
        }
        if self.userImage != nil{            
           self.userImage.removeAll()
        }
        if self.currentData != nil{            
           self.currentData.removeAll()
        }
        if self.taskDetails != nil{            
           self.taskDetails.removeAll()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .background)

@objc private func refreshData() {

if isRefreshing {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    return
}
isRefreshing = true
print("refresh")
guard let url = URL(string: taskURL) else {
    return
}
dataTask?.cancel()
let request = URLRequest(url: url)

dataTask = 
defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self](dataOpt, response, error) in 
defer {
  self?.dataTask = nil
}

if let error = error {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loading Error", message: "No Internet Connection. Please try again later.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        return

} else if 
  let data = dataOpt,
  let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
  response.statusCode == 200 {  
        self.data.removeAll()
        self.userImage.removeAll()
        self.currentData.removeAll()
        self.taskDetails.removeAll()      
    let appdata = try? JSONDecoder().decode(TaskList.self, from: data)

    for data in appdata!{

          self.data.append(CellData.init(image: UIImage(named: "Profile"), message: data.name, checkImage: data.status))
            self.userImage.append("")

          self.taskDetails.append(TaskDetails.init(status: data.status, assigned: data.assigneUid, time: data.duedateTsUTC, priority: data.priority, desc: data.desc, uid: data.uid))


    }

    self.currentData = self.data

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.searchBar.text = ""
        self.isRefreshing = false
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
}


dataTask?.resume()

}
```

Comment: This if-block is only to avoid refreshing again and again. I dont want to stop the method there. And it does not work.